# Random position from a boolean array

Tags: python, numpy, random

I have a 2D boolean array, and I want to generate one random location where it's `1`.

```
array([[0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
       [0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
       [0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1],
       [0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1]])
```

Example output:

```
(2,2)
```

Comment: 2 methods I could think of: 1) rejection sampling, randomly generate from entire array and only keep if it's `1`, 2) linearly search for the position where the cumsum is a randInt from `[1,  arraySum]`

Comment: I have no answer, but an idea. You could pick a random element. If it is 1, you return it. If it is 0 then you check the following element. If it is also 0, you again go to the following.
This will work very effectively. But it has the problem that the result is not random. So I think, you could implement something that compensates this and makes it random again. Perhaps if you check various elements in parallel.

Answer (score 6):

Something like this may work:

```
import numpy as np
l = np.array([[0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
       [0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
       [0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1],
       [0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1]])
random = np.random.choice(np.sum(l))
np.argwhere(l)[random]
```

result:

> [0, 4]

Answer (score 1):

You can use a while loop until the `random.choice()` function generates an index that references to a `1` value inside 2D list:

```
import random
import numpy as np

l = np.array([[0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
       [0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
       [0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1],
       [0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1]])

i, j = random.choice(range(len(l))), random.choice(range(len(l[0])))
while l[i][j] != 1:
  i, j = random.choice(range(len(l))), random.choice(range(len(l[0])))

print((i, j), l[i][j])
```

> (4, 6) 1

Comment: I'm sure rejection sampling would work, but in a large, sparse array, it will take much time to find a valid location, right?

Comment: @shukai-ni Not really, depends on the density of ones inside it

Answer (score 0):

OK first of all let's make the boolean array a boolean array:

```
bool_arr = np.array([[0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
       [0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
       [0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1],
       [0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1]])

bool_arr = (bool_arr==1)
```

Next I'll proceed by creating an indices matrix of the same shape of the boolean array:

```
indices = np.moveaxis(np.c_[np.meshgrid(np.arange(bool_arr.shape[1]), np.arange(bool_arr.shape[0]))][::-1], 0,-1)
```

this matrix has the property that:

```
indices[x, y] = [x, y] #for each valid x, y
```

in this way I can mask the indices matrix with the boolean array retrieving all the `True` positions:

```
indices[bool_arr]
```

out:

```
array([[0, 3],
       [0, 4],
       [0, 5],
       [1, 3],
       [1, 4],
       [1, 5],
       [1, 6],
       [1, 7],
       [2, 2],
       [2, 3],
       [2, 4],
       [2, 5],
       [2, 6],
       [2, 7],
       [3, 1],
       [3, 2],
       [3, 3],
       [3, 7],
       [4, 1],
       [4, 2],
       [4, 3],
       [4, 6],
       [4, 7]])
```

Now I can finally sample from this list of indices:

```
indices[bool_arr][np.random.randint(bool_arr.sum())]
```

Answer (score -1):

Here are some statistics I got for 3 methods x dense/sparse arrays. For stability, I would stick with `cumSum` method.

```
def rejection_randPos(l):
    r, c = l.shape
    i, j = random.randint(0, r - 1), random.randint(0, c - 1)
    while not l[i, j]:
        i, j = random.randint(0, r - 1), random.randint(0, c - 1)
    return i, j

def cumSum_randPos(l):
    c = l.shape[1]
    target = random.randint(1, l.sum())
    idx = np.argmax(l.cumsum() >= target)
    return idx // c, idx % c

def argWhere_randPos(l):
    target = random.randint(0, l.sum() - 1)
    return np.argwhere(l)[target]


A = np.random.rand(5, 8) < 0.8
%timeit rejection_randPos(A)
%timeit cumSum_randPos(A)
%timeit argWhere_randPos(A)
B = np.random.rand(5, 8) < 0.05
%timeit rejection_randPos(B)
%timeit cumSum_randPos(B)
%timeit argWhere_randPos(B)
```

=>

```
1.92 µs ± 28.9 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000000 loops each)
9.81 µs ± 182 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000 loops each)
12.4 µs ± 148 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000 loops each)
28 µs ± 311 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)
10.1 µs ± 753 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000 loops each)
12.3 µs ± 264 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000 loops each)
```